# Submit and edit font end custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to figure out if the following is possible with WordPress.

I want my visitors to be able to register an account and get redirected to a profile page where they can enter some fields to update their profiles. These fields will be saved in a custom post type which I created with the CPT UI and ACF plugins. And every time the user visits this page, he can edit the same fields again to update his profile info (preferably these fields are still populated with the previously entered info).

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: ACF [has a how-to](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/) for front-end forms using their plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite possible.

You want to pass into the form the user's id and make them author of the custom post you create programmatically when they submit the form. Each user will have one post of that type. By default, when a user goes to that page, it will load a form with data from the only post of that type they have.

Optionally, for admins you can add the possibility of overriding user id with a get parameter so they could see the page as any other user (except other admins - don't forget this check!) - this is quite useful when you have many users: it allows you to see the page as a different user and debug faster, without the need to log into their account.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Since I'm not very skilled in PHP I have to ask a friend to do this for me. If you have more tips I would love to hear them.